# how to format number the using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remove the number which are coming after "." then i want to format the number **(16810900.211233)** to like this **(16,810,900)**  but i dont know how to do that here is my  html is this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.webrupee.com/font" />
<div class="main">
<p class="active">10200.00</p>
<p class="in_active">16810900.211233</p>
<p class="active">0</p>
<p class="in_active">-</p>
<p class="active">1278200.543554</p>
<p class="in_active">-</p>
<p class="active">-</p>
<p class="in_active">9,890.656</p>
<p class="active">10,200</p>
<p class="in_active">16810900</p>
<p class="active">0</p>
<p class="in_active">-</p>
<p class="active">1278200.09</p>
<p class="in_active">-</p>
<p class="active">-</p>
<p class="in_active">9890.00</p>
</div>​
```

i tried here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/Hrac3/2/)

Comment: Some basic round function should do. See e.g. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098685/jquery-rounding-numbers-to-2-digits-after-comma][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098685/jquery-rounding-numbers-to-2-digits-after-comma

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I format numbers as money in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Ripped from http://ntt.cc/2008/04/25/6-very-basic-but-very-useful-javascript-number-format-functions-for-web-developers.html

No point in reinventing the wheel.. :)

```
/**
* Formats the number according to the ‘format’ string;
* adherses to the american number standard where a comma
* is inserted after every 3 digits.
*  note: there should be only 1 contiguous number in the format,
* where a number consists of digits, period, and commas
*        any other characters can be wrapped around this number, including ‘$’, ‘%’, or text
*        examples (123456.789):
*          ‘0′ - (123456) show only digits, no precision
*          ‘0.00′ - (123456.78) show only digits, 2 precision
*          ‘0.0000′ - (123456.7890) show only digits, 4 precision
*          ‘0,000′ - (123,456) show comma and digits, no precision
*          ‘0,000.00′ - (123,456.78) show comma and digits, 2 precision
*          ‘0,0.00′ - (123,456.78) shortcut method, show comma and digits, 2 precision
*
* @method format
* @param format {string} the way you would like to format this text
* @return {string} the formatted number
* @public
*/ 

Number.prototype.format = function(format) {
  if (! isType(format, ’string’)) {return ”;} // sanity check 

  var hasComma = -1 < format.indexOf(’,'),
    psplit = format.stripNonNumeric().split(’.'),
    that = this; 

  // compute precision
  if (1 < psplit.length) {
    // fix number precision
    that = that.toFixed(psplit[1].length);
  }
  // error: too many periods
  else if (2 < psplit.length) {
    throw(’NumberFormatException: invalid format, formats should have no more than 1 period: ‘ + format);
  }
  // remove precision
  else {
    that = that.toFixed(0);
  } 

  // get the string now that precision is correct
  var fnum = that.toString(); 

  // format has comma, then compute commas
  if (hasComma) {
    // remove precision for computation
    psplit = fnum.split(’.'); 

    var cnum = psplit[0],
      parr = [],
      j = cnum.length,
      m = Math.floor(j / 3),
      n = cnum.length % 3 || 3; // n cannot be ZERO or causes infinite loop 

    // break the number into chunks of 3 digits; first chunk may be less than 3
    for (var i = 0; i < j; i += n) {
      if (i != 0) {n = 3;}
      parr[parr.length] = cnum.substr(i, n);
      m -= 1;
    } 

    // put chunks back together, separated by comma
    fnum = parr.join(’,'); 

    // add the precision back in
    if (psplit[1]) {fnum += ‘.’ + psplit[1];}
  } 

  // replace the number portion of the format with fnum
  return format.replace(/[\d,?\.?]+/, fnum);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize#numbers) library is the simplest way to accomplish your goal.  This allows you to specify a format and account for the way that different cultures handle number grouping.  For example:

```
Globalize.format(Math.round(16810900.211233))
```

results in `16,810,900`

Comment: Wouldn't round() on 16810900.711233 change the result to 16810901? I think parseInt() or Math.Floor() might work here instead unless the OP wants to round up/down.

Comment: @Chris Right - I wasn't sure what the OP needed.  Actually, Globalize has a number format parameter that assumes rounding so `Globalize.format(16810900.711233, 'n0')` results in `16,810,901`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("p").text(function(i, v) {
    if (v == "-")
        return v; // or whatever you want to to with these
    v = v.split(".")[0]; // remove anything after the first "."
    v = v.replace(/[^\d]/g, ""); // remove non-numeric characters
    var group = 3;
    var min = v.length > 4 ? group : 4; // format thousands without separator
    for (var res=[], i=v.length; i>min; i-=group)
        res.push(v.substr(i-group, group));
    res.push(v.substr(0,i));
    return res.reverse().join(".");
});
```

This will format numbers even with the thousand separator not set for 4-character-numbers.

Comment: Hi Bergi, This is working fine. But some numbers are not formatting pls check this link http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/Hrac3/3/ i tried here

Comment: Usually thousands are not formatted with a separator. My [new version](http://jsfiddle.net/Hrac3/4/) makes that more evident.