# How to remove zero after decimal point on a float using javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery: rounding numbers to 2 digits after comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098685/jquery-rounding-numbers-to-2-digits-after-comma)

While printing out a number in JavaScript, I only want keep only three digits after the decimal point. The code I am using shows more than 8 digits after the decimal point. Could anyone guide me on how to remove the remaining digits using JavaScript.

This is my JavaScript code:

```
function  doMath() { 

   var nvalue; var amount;
   var price= 0.27;
   nvalue = document.getElementById("message").value;

   amount=(nvalue*price);

   document.getElementById("total").value=amount ;

}
```

Output:

> 4.050000000000001

I want:

> 4.050

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Perhaps this question answers your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098685/jquery-rounding-numbers-to-2-digits-after-comma

Comment: Without `toFixed()`: `Math.ceil(amount * 1000) / 1000`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this
`amount=amount.toFixed(3);`

Answer (score 1):

use toFixed() method  of javascript

> toFixed() method converts a number into a string, keeping a specified number of decimals.

```
var amount= amount.toFixed(3);  //3 digits after decimal
```

Answer (score 1):

I would *not* recommend using `.toFixed()` for rounding numbers, since it returns a **string**. In your case, this is probably quite ok, since it looks like it's for display, but in general, do some maths:

```
function betterToFixed(num, decPlaces) {
  var factor = Math.pow(10, decPlaces);
  return Math.round(num * factor) / factor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `toFixed()`:

```
amount = amount.toFixed(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
amount= amount.toFixed(3);
```

this will give you the solution you want