# How would I get this function to only return three numbers?

Tags: javascript, html

```
**<script>
function roundNum() {
var f = document.getElementById("f").value;
var g = document.getElementById("g").value
var g = g-u
document.getElementById("ng").innerHTML = g
</script>**
```

I am trying to receive a three-digit answer (example: 95.7, instead of 95.6923531)

Comment: You can use `.toFixed()` to convert the number to a string with a maximum number of fraction digits. You cannot restrict actual numbers to a specific number of decimal places because numbers are *binary* floating point.

Comment: when you have a problem like this just use google. the chances that you are the first person who wants to format a number is equal to 0 ;)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098685/rounding-numbers-to-2-digits-after-comma/32761885

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript `toFixed()` method.

Example:

```
var x = 9.656;
x.toFixed(1);           // returns 9.7
x.toFixed(2);           // returns 9.66
x.toFixed(4);           // returns 9.6560
x.toFixed(6);           // returns 9.656000
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Syntax: 
**number.toFixed(x)**

```js
var num = 95.6923531;
console.log(num.toFixed(1));
console.log(num.toFixed(2));
console.log(num.toFixed(3));
```