# Javascript returning NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing

I'm attempting to display a subtotal each time a customer enters a quantity. However, when I loop through my inputs, I get a `NaN` as the total. I believe it may be the way I'm declaring the `subtotal` variable in my script, but I haven't come across this before:

```
$('.item-qty input').bind('keyup', function(){

   var subtotal = 0.0;

   $('.item-qty input').each(function(){
      var class = $(this).attr('id');
      var qty = $(this).val();                     
      var price = $('.'+class).html();

      price = parseFloat(price);
      qty = parseInt(qty);
      subtotal = subtotal + (price * qty);
   });

   $('.subtotal input').val(subtotal);
});
```

Comment: Can you give an example for the values? `parseFloat` and `parseInt` will return `NaN` if they cannot parse the string into a number. You should not use floating point values for financial computations because of the rounding errors. Make all your computations in cents. Also, in some browsers (like FF5) you will not be able to use `class` as variable name, as it is a reserved keyword.

Comment: Why not to try to debug? Go over steps and check content of variables,  this will help you to localize problem.

Comment: Also, just as a hint, try not to use "class" as a variable-name. Some browsers might not like that.

Comment: When I loop through, the subtotal gets calculated correctly the first time. The next time it goes through the loop, the subtotal is NaN.

Comment: And yet another thing: Don't forget to pass the radix to `parseInt`, otherwise you will get problems with numerical strings starting with `0`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[`parseFloat`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseFloat.asp) and [`parseInt`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseInt.asp) can return `NaN` if the first character of the string cannot be converted to a number.

So, I would safeguard against it like this (`NaN` is a *falsy* value):

```
price = parseFloat(price) || 0;
qty = parseInt(qty, 10) || 0;
```

Arithmetic operations on numbers with the value `NaN` almost always result in `NaN` (`NaN + 5` will result in `NaN`.) That means, if only *one* of the input cannot be parsed by `parseFloat` or `parseInt`, your current code would end up calculating `NaN` for the subtotal.

---

It's already been mentioned in the comments (by [Felix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling) mostly) but I think it's worth the emphasis as these are important concerns:

- Always pass the `radix` argument to the `parseInt` function;
- Do not use `class` for variable names: It's a reserved (not used, but reserved) keyword;
- Don't expect the subtotal to be [*perfectly* accurate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876536/precise-financial-calculation-in-javascript-what-are-the-gotchas) unless you do your calculations in cents.

Comment: It is not the case that `NaN + 5 === NaN` because `NaN` is the one value that is [not identical to itself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565164/what-is-the-rationale-for-all-comparisons-returning-false-for-ieee754-nan-values).  Maybe `isNaN(NaN + 5)` would be better.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Edited my answer accordingly. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer .. Good one