# Why keeps sum returning a false value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some input values inside a form like this:

```
<tr>
  <td>
      <input type="text" disabled class="qty" value="1" name="quantity">
  </td>
  <td>
    <span class="euro">€</span><input type="text" disabled class="price" value="0,60">
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
      <input type="text" disabled class="qty" value="1" name="quantity">
  </td>
  <td>
    <span class="euro">€</span><input type="text" disabled class="price" value="0,25">
  </td>
</tr>
// below table row is empty because product is not on stock! //
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
//etc...
```

I try to sum the `qty` and `price` input values but my script keeps returning `NaN` as result. I think it is because when a product is not on stock the table cells are empty. Therefore returning `NaN` or `undefined`.
 I've read numerous threads like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7264752/javascript-returning-nan) but that doesn't fix my problem.

What I have is this:

```
function update_amounts(){
  var sum = 0.0;
  $('#inspiration .table tbody tr').each(function() {
    var qty = $(this).find('.qty').val();
    var price = $(this).find('.price').val();
    console.log(price, qty);
    var amount = (qty*price)
        sum+=amount;
  });
  $('.total').text(sum);    
}
```

What I already tried is this:

```
var qty = parseInt($(this).find('.qty').val()) || 0;
var price = parseFloat($(this).find('.price').val()) || 0;
```

And:

```
var qty = $(this).find('.qty').val();
var price = $(this).find('.price').val();
qty= parseInt(qty) || 0;
price= parseFloat(price) || 0;
console.log returns

    (2) 1 0
        0 0
    (3) 1 0
```

Below is what console.log returns for the original code (first one is price, second qty):

```
0,60 1
0,90 1
undefined undefined
0,14 1
0,12 1
0,75 1
```

I don't know any new option to get this fixed!

Comment: What does it return for the code you tried?

Comment: @Evan Knowles: Always NaN. Whatever I try

Comment: Your code works on my side, with the `|| 0`. Perhaps you had a caching issue?

Comment: @JaapVermoolen: And the `log` calls? `parseInt`/`parseFloat` never return `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `.` character to start the floating point, not `,`.

`value="0,60"` will not be treated as a number. `value="0.60"` will be.

```
%  node
> "0.60" * 5
3
> "0,60" * 5
NaN
>
```

When run through `parseFloat`, it will hit the `,` and stop treating the rest as a number, so you end up with `0`.

```
> parseFloat("0.60") * 5
3
> parseFloat("0,60") * 5
0
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: @JaapVermoolen price should be `0.60`, not `0,60`.

Comment: @JaapVermoolen — I've added an example to the answer.

Comment: `0,60` will be treated as a number, but the number will be `0` because it stops parsing when it hits the `,`.

Comment: @Barmar — If it was JavaScript code then the `,` would be treated as a comma operator (so it wouldn't stop parsing per se), but it isn't JavaScript. It is a string pulled out of the DOM.

Comment: @Quentin `parseFloat("0,60")` => `0`.

Comment: @Barmar — Ah. I was looking at the original code rather than the selection of non-working attempts to fix it.

Comment: Conversely, I didn't notice that the original didn't have parseFloat.

Comment: @Quentin: Thx! Excellent... Never thought of that because the system pulls the price out of a Twig template. Therefore uses a comma instead of a point.