# Add Javascript to replace Span tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an online store that has limited access to make any correct edits to code.

I am trying to implement proper Price Schema as they have:

```
<span itemprop="price">$57.00</span>
```

This is incorrect.

It needs to be set up like this

```
<span itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD">$</span> 
<span itemprop="price">57.00</span>
```

Is there something in JavaScript or jQuery that can manipulate this by separating the Currency Symbol and Price?

Thanks

Comment: Well yes, manipulating DOM nodes is the primary purpose of JavaScript in the browser. Where are you stuck?

Comment: I think that JS will not help in your case.  It will be to late since theres no pricecurrency initially in the DOM

Answer (score 1):

You get the **ELEMENT** text:

```
var value = $("span[itemprop='price'").text();
```

Then you could generate the html using regex like:

```
var html = '$57.00'.replace(/([^\d])(\d+)/,
 function(all, group1, group2){ 
 return 'some html here =' + group1 + '= more hear =' + group2  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Somthing along the lines of

```
// find all span's with itemprop price
document.querySelectorAll("span[itemprop='price']").forEach(function(sp){ 
    // grab currency (first char)
    var currency = sp.innerText.substr(0,1);
    // remove first char from price val
    sp.innerText = sp.innerText.substr(1);

    // create new element (our price-currency span)
    var currencySpan = document.createElement("span");
    currencySpan.innerText = currency;
    currencySpan.setAttribute("itemprop", "priceCurrency");
    currencySpan.setAttribute("content", "USD");


    // Append it before the old price span
    sp.parentNode.insertBefore(currencySpan, sp);
});
```

Should do what your after.

See demo at: https://jsfiddle.net/dfufq40p/1/ (updated to make effect more obvious)

Answer (score 0):

Might not be 100% bug-free, but it should get you started:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var n = document.getElementsByTagName('*')
for(var i=0;i<n.length;i++)
{

  if(n[i].hasAttribute('itemprop')) //get elements with itemprop attribute
  {
     var p = n[i].parentNode

     var ih = n[i].innerHTML //grab the innerHTML
     var num = parseFloat(ih) //get numeric part of the innerHTML - effectively strips out the $-sign

     n[i].innerHTML = num

     //create new span & insert it before the old one
       var new_span = document.createElement('span')
       new_span.innerHTML = '$'
       new_span.setAttribute('itemprop', 'priceCurrency')
       new_span.setAttribute('currency', 'USD')

       p.insertBefore(new_span, n[i])
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: parseFloat will fail on the "$" character:  [parseFloat on non-numeric char](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7264816/5758637)

Answer (score 0):

This should work -- querySelectorAll should be a bit faster, and the regex will work with more than just USD, I believe.

```
function fixItemPropSpan() {
  var n = document.querySelectorAll('[itemprop]');
  for (var i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {

    var p = n[i].parentNode;
    var ih = n[i].innerHTML;
    var num = Number(ih.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, ""));

    n[i].innerHTML = num;

    //create new span & insert it before the old one
    var new_span = document.createElement('span');
    new_span.innerHTML = '$';
    new_span.setAttribute('itemprop', 'priceCurrency');
    new_span.setAttribute('currency', 'USD');

    p.insertBefore(new_span, n[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a suggestion of how you can make this work, though i would not suggest doing it like this (too many cases for `content=""`).

[Example](http://jsbin.com/daquse/edit?html,js,output) of the logic you could use to transform the incorrect format to the correct one.

Hope you find it useful. :]