# Adding variables together returns string rather than number

Tags: jquery

I've got three variables I'm trying to sum the values. For two of these items, I need the form value to read differently, so i've created an attribute `cost` to pull the cost through with.  My code is:

```
var opt1 = parseFloat($('#ac1 option:selected').attr('cost')).toFixed(2);
var opt2 = parseFloat($('#ac2 option:selected').attr('cost')).toFixed(2);
var base = parseFloat($('#original_price').val());
var newprice = opt1+opt2+base;
```

if opt1 should be 4.00, opt2 6.50 and base 10.00, it's giving me an output of `4.006.5010.00` instead of `20.50`

any ideas on where i'm going wrong?

Comment: `toFixed` returns a string (so `opt1` and `opt2` contain strings) and [don't make financial calculations with floating points numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876536/precise-financial-calculation-in-javascript-what-are-the-gotchas).

Comment: @Felix Thanks - Good advice for a website I'm writing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your `toFixed` method turning the number into a string?  It must be. Try wrapping parseFloat around the entire call.

```
var newprice = parseFloat(opt1)+parseFloat(opt2)+base;
```

Also, try testing if opt1 and opt2 are strings

```
console.log(typeof opt1 === 'string');
```

Comment: yep, that did it. my javascript is still a bit rough. hadn't fully appreciated how toFixed worked. Thanks muchly!