# How to parse a big decimal number to only 2 decimal places?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How is floating point stored? When does it matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56947/how-is-floating-point-stored-when-does-it-matter)

Here is an example with 3 options and 2 different problems. http://jsfiddle.net/pEpFA/7/

1. option 1 - ground / displays properly.
2. option 2 - express / omits the '0' from the value
3. option 3 - overnight / add's `000000000000000` to the total.

How do i get this to work properly? I want the outcome to be displayed like option 1. Is this a javaScript bug?

## HTML

```
<label><input type="radio" name="print" class="option" data-number="25.72" /> UPS Ground </label>
<br>
<label><input type="radio" name="print" class="option" data-number="80.90" /> UPS Express </label>
<br>
<label><input type="radio" name="print" class="option" data-number="112.93" /> UPS Overnight </label>

<br><br>
Shipping
$<span id="ship_total"></span>

<br>
Final Total
$<span id="new_total"></span>
```

## jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('label').click(function() {
         var total = 0;

          $('.option:checked').each(function() {
              total += Number($(this).data('number'));   
          });
              $('#ship_total').text(total);

                  //php echos the subtotal
                 var sub_total = 550.25;

                 var ship_total = ($("#ship_total").text());

                var final_total = parseFloat(sub_total) + parseFloat(ship_total);

        $('#new_total').text(final_total);
    });

    });
```

See jsfiddle DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/pEpFA/7/

Comment: What exactly is/are the problems.

Comment: The problems are explained in the first 3 sentences. Did you downvote me?

Comment: Javascript can add just fine...

Comment: Ok see my demo for clarification .. Why the downvotes?

Comment: Because there's nothing wrong with the math. The problem is displaying numbers with certain number of decimal places.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56947/how-is-floating-point-stored-when-does-it-matter

Comment: @sachleen: Don't forget that [JavaScript's math is broken](http://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/1048572) (because it is floating-point-artithmetik); However this does not seem to be an issue here

Comment: @fabio: Could you explain the error at option #3? It just displays fine.

Comment: IMHO the downvotes were not just in this case. I described my problem clearly in a numbered list. Provided all code. and a Demo for easy tweaking/testing

Comment: @bergi #3 was corrected by marcelo it was showing the final total as `$663.000000000000018`

Comment: #2 is because trailing zeros are ignored after the decimal point, you have to use `.toFixed()`; #3 is because floating-point math is not precise (see the link I added above).

Comment: As for the downvotes: I think that's because floats just work like that (and that's in all languages, not only js), and that's very well documented. I voted to close as duplicate (but didn't downvote, for the record).

Comment: @Bergi #3 is because of floating-point math.

Comment: @bfavaretto I was not aware of the float issue. I was perplexed at how it worked correctly in 1 instance and not in the others. Thank you for your input. I'm sure less experienced people can learn from this question.

Comment: *related:* [Precise Financial Calculation in JavaScript. What Are the Gotchas?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876536/precise-financial-calculation-in-javascript-what-are-the-gotchas).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/pEpFA/9/  (Updated all values)

Pay attention to those lines below in the fiddle above:

```
 total = total.toFixed(2);
 ...
 final_total = final_total.toFixed(2);
```

Comment: Just 1 issue - see option express is not displaying .90 but .9

Comment: @fabio use toFixed when you display that number too... come on now, he gave you the function you need to fix your problems, you could at least use it yourself.

Comment: Just use the same function in the variable you're applying to ship total!

Comment: $('#ship_total').text(total.toFixed(2));

Comment: @fabio, updated in the fiddle, look it and please try to understand what I've done.

Comment: thanks @MarceloAssis i will accept your answer

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the following

```
final_total.toFixed(Number);
```

Comment: @fabio yes it does... you don't even use it in your demo.

Comment: Are you sure? I just tested and it worked...
    final_total.toFixed(2);

Comment: I was about to post an answer, and two more came up!! I wrapped the full function like this: var final_total = (parseFloat(sub_total) + parseFloat(ship_total)).toFixed(2); Here's a jsfiddle of it: http://jsfiddle.net/pEpFA/10/