# Correcting floating math broken by multiplying, is it ok?

Tags: javascript, math

I have multiple calculations which have troubles because of floating math problem in js.
I'm trying to fix it by multiplying all parts of equation by 1000 and then dividing the result by 1000.

```
var a = 16924.83,
    b = 16835.61;

var c = a-b; //outputs 89.22000000000116
var d = (1000*a-1000*b)/1000;  //outputs 89.22 and seems to be working correct
```

Is it ok to do correction of floating math problem this way?

I did read [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Why not just round the result to the desired number of decimal places...

Comment: Work in hundredths and scale for display at the very end.

Comment: Related: [Precise Financial Calculation in JavaScript. What Are the Gotchas?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876536/precise-financial-calculation-in-javascript-what-are-the-gotchas)

Comment: This might work, but it's always possible that some combinations of numbers will fail. If these are monetary values you're working with I'd recommend you store and work in integers (i.e. multiply them by 100 and fix to zero decimal places), then divide by 100 and fix again for display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should round after multiplying:

```
var d = (Math.round(1000*a)-Math.round(1000*b))/1000;
```

Just multiplying may not solve the problem. When you assign

```
var a = 16924.83;
```

it might internally represent this as something like `16924.8300001`, so when you multiply by `1000` you get `16924830.001`. You need to round to get rid of that fraction.

Comment: Can I round Math.round(1000*a - 1000*b)/1000 - it's just takes less coding, but I don't know if there will be difference. Suppose not?

Comment: I think that will work as long as you don't add/subtract more than 5 variables inside the `Math.round`. Rounding each variable works more generally.