# Undefined is not a function"""

Tags: javascript

Why do I get Uncaught type error: undefined is not a function"""
I have no J Query in my page

Here is my code:

```
function CDec(Currency) {
    var number = Currency.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,"");
    return number;
}
```

Calling of the function

```
SellPrice.value = "$" +  CurrencyFormat(CDec(ListPrice.value * (1 + CDec(Markup.value))) * CDec(Mutiplier.value));
```

and

```
Markup.value =   CurrencyFormat(100 * (CDec(SellPrice.value)-CDec(Netcost.value)) / CDec(Netcost.value)) + "%"
```

Comment: `replace` is not a method on the `Currency` object?

Comment: Well Currency is supposed to be a string but may contain 10.5% or $100 or skcnbdskcbdks

Comment: How can I make this work Thanks guys

Comment: Show a full example of how this code is being called.

Comment: We need to see what your Currency.replace function looks like, I'm guessing it doesn't return anything

Comment: This looks like `Currency` is a `Number`, yes?

Comment: Currency is a number in your example so `Currency.toString().replace(...)` (This makes replacing non-numerics a bit redundant ...)

Comment: The result of a `*` operation is always a number, not a string.

Comment: Without full snippet, I can only suggest the easiest way is a pre-convertion from number to string, `Currency = Currency.toString();` at the top of `CDec` function

Comment: I fixed the problem by adding tostring indeed it was wrong for me to assume it was a string. I wish we could define the variables in javascript. Maybe you can I don't know but I am new to javascript.

Comment: @PieterdeVries would you mind accept/upvote for me ? :]

Comment: @elaijuh It won't let me

Comment: @PieterdeVries, just post my answer for your accept, :]

Comment: Its worth noting that your CDec() implementation would convert any negative number to a positive one which may have undesirable implications ...

Comment: @Alex K Please let me know how I can improve my code as you are sugessting

Comment: In your example you pass a valid number (the result of a mathematical expression) to CDec() so there is no point in calling CDec() in the first place. For other unknown values, deal with a leading `-`

Comment: I don't quit understand I am using this to make sure that the user has entered a valid amount and to make sure that the calculation can be done correctly. Let me know if I am missing something or a snippet might help. Thanks for you help.

Comment: I guess I should have Explained my self better, I am having textbox values in the CDec function. The texboxes could contain $12.00 or 33.5% and I cant do a calculation on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function CDec(Currency) {
    Currency = Currency.toString();
    var number = Currency.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,"");
    return number;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply convert numbers that are passed as parameter to string, e.g.:

```
function CDec(Currency) {
    var number = (Currency + '').replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,"");
    return number;
}
```

But I would recommend you to validate input data first.

Comment: This seems to look like a hack .tosring looks better in my opinion but your code does work.

Comment: There're lots of ways to convert number to string. And **mostly** adding an empty string is the fastest way. Of course it depends on browser and amount of conversions. See more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765398/whats-the-best-way-to-convert-a-number-to-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

Given your comments you would be better off replacing *known* possible characters and validating the return result.

```
function CDec(Currency) {
    if (typeof Currency !== "number")
        Currency = parseFloat(Currency.toString().replace(/[£$%]/g, ""));

    return Currency;
}

console.log( CDec(1.22) );
console.log( CDec(-1.22) );
console.log( CDec("$1.22") );
console.log( CDec("$1.22%") );
console.log( CDec("-£1.22") );

if (isNaN(CDec("Woof"))
   alert("invalid!");
```

You should also probably scale your values: [Precise Financial Calculation in JavaScript. What Are the Gotchas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876536/precise-financial-calculation-in-javascript-what-are-the-gotchas)